# ${{ parameters.Key }} and ${{ parameters.Value }} returning nothing

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I just now tried executing the sample pipeline provided [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/runtime-parameters?view=azure-devops&tabs=script#loop-through-parameters) and the echo of ${{ parameters.Key }} and ${{ parameters.Value }} is printing out nothing. I'm sure I've tried something like the following in the past and it did work. Might it be a regression?

```
parameters:
- name: param_1
  type: string
  default: a string value
- name: param_2
  type: string
  default: default
- name: param_3
  type: number
  default: 2
- name: param_4
  type: boolean
  default: true

steps: 
- ${{ each parameter in parameters }}:
  - script: echo '${{ parameters.Key }} -> ${{ parameters.Value }}'
```

Comment: Hi friend, please check if the several answers below can resolve your issue, if yes, you could accept it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use `${{ parameter.Key }} -> ${{ parameter.Value }}` instead of `${{ parameters.Key }} -> ${{ parameters.Value }}`.

This works on my side:

```
parameters:
- name: param_1
  type: string
  default: a string value
- name: param_2
  type: string
  default: default
- name: param_3
  type: number
  default: 2
- name: param_4
  type: boolean
  default: true

steps: 
- ${{ each parameter in parameters }}:
  - script: echo '${{ parameter.Key }} -> ${{ parameter.Value }}'
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: When I tried it a few weeks ago I probably saw and fixed myself the error. This time I did not identify it. Thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

Walter is correct, the issue is with documentation. I made a [PR](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-devops-docs/pull/10072) to fix that.

It should be

```yaml
- ${{ each parameter in parameters }}:
  - script: echo '${{ parameter.Key }} -> ${{ parameter.Value }}'
```

and in documentation is `parameters.Key` and `parameters.Value` what is wrong.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to double checking this. I was working just a few weeks ago because I tested it out. Now I wanted to put it in a pipeline where it made sense being able to log all of the passed runtime parameters values and nothing gets returned.